# Auto refresh page using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have a jsp page which shows the data of a queue.I want the new data to be displayed automatically whenever it come to the queue,dont have to reload the page again.

Is this possible by ajax?any example how to do or tutorials..

Thanks,

Comment: Yes.  And SO isn't a tutorial finding service.

Comment: ok then can you give me one simple example ?

Comment: U can use  jquery $.ajax() method and setInterval()